# how do I wait for database call to finish

Tags: java, android, database, multithreading

I have the following code in my Android app that reads data from a local SQL database into some variables:

```
Context context = getContext();
localSettingsManager = new LocalSettingsManager(context);

LocalDatabase localDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, LocalDatabase.class, context.getResources().getString(R.string.database_name))
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();

DatabaseDAO databaseDAO = localDatabase.DatabaseDAO();
Observable.just(databaseDAO)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(dao -> {
                    Device device = dao.getByCid(localSettingsManager.getDeviceCid());
                    if(device!=null) {
                        currentSerialNumberString = device.serialNumber;
                        currentProxyConfigUrlString = device.proxyConfigURL;
                        currentIMEI1String = device.imei1;
                        currentCarrier1String = device.imei1Carrier;
                        currentIMEI2String = device.imei2;
                        currentCarrier2String = device.imei2Carrier;
                        currentBrandString = device.brand;
                        currentManufacturerString = device.manufacturer;
                        currentModelString = device.model;
                        currentMarketString = device.marketPlaceCID;
                    }

                });
    // wait for data to be read from database before accessing variables
```

The problem I am having is that when I access the variables that are assigned the data from the database immediately after the database call, they will be read before they are assigned. While I can 'fix' the problem by putting in a half second delay, this doesn't feel right.  What is the right way to wait for the database read to finish before continuing program execution?

Comment: basically related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value. you have all the values available to you when you subscribe, so either use it there, or use something like live data to observe onto the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways,

1. do not use threading, that`s mean  you will use the main thread to use database and after  that continue the other code
2. in rx-java after that is completed you can use a LiveData Or MutableLiveData and observe it on onCreate method and there are the place you will write other code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess one way is to take away the call to subscribe:

```
Context context = getContext();
        localSettingsManager = new LocalSettingsManager(context);

        LocalDatabase localDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, LocalDatabase.class, context.getResources().getString(R.string.database_name))
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();

        DatabaseDAO databaseDAO = localDatabase.DatabaseDAO();

        Device device = databaseDAO.getByCid(localSettingsManager.getDeviceCid());
        if (device != null) {
            currentSerialNumberString = device.serialNumber;
            currentProxyConfigUrlString = device.proxyConfigURL;
            currentIMEI1String = device.imei1;
            currentCarrier1String = device.imei1Carrier;
            currentIMEI2String = device.imei2;
            currentCarrier2String = device.imei2Carrier;
            currentBrandString = device.brand;
            currentManufacturerString = device.manufacturer;
            currentModelString = device.model;
            currentMarketString = device.marketPlaceCID;
        }

        doneButton = view.findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        currentMarket = view.findViewById(R.id.currentMarket);
        currentMarket.setText(String.valueOf(currentMarketString));
```